# Find the Intersect between two View?

Tags: android

How can find the intersection between two ImageView ???

For this I tried this but no progress

**Can anyone suggest me to do this?**

**Code snnipet**

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    Rect rect =new Rect();
    imageView.getHitRect(rect);

    Rect rect1 = new Rect();
    imageView2.getHitRect(rect1);

    if(Rect.intersects(rect, rect1)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "hoho", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

**xml file :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".IntersectActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="121dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: At what point in the life cycle of an activity/fragment is your code snippet executed? `getHitRect()` will not yield anything useful until after the views have been measured, laid out, etc. In other words: you can't just chuck that snippet in, for example, `onCreate()` or `onStart()` - that won't work.

Comment: then where should I need to call this thing ? @MH.

Comment: what is the possible  solution for this ? @MH.

Comment: So , where should i put my code ? cz I can't understand the meaning of "after layout phase"  @pskink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, in `onCreate()`, android has not yet created the view, so any attempts get get the width height location of a point etc won't work.

Instead, override `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focus)` and put your code in there

Comment: you dont have to do that, just post a Runnable in onCreate and do your stuff in its run() method

Comment: If I'll use the drag and drop functionality on one ImageView that time what should I do for this? Like : one ImageView drag onto another static ImageView.

Comment: @user26534 - I am not sure if it will be called automatically, but you can call it manually, for example, in the 'drop' part of your code, call `onWindowFocusChanged(true)` and that code will be run

Comment: did you log both Rect? if so, what was the output? now use getGlobalVisibleRect() instead of getHitRect()

Comment: @jcw : I tried but didn't get the intersection b/w them ?? something else way to do this .....

Comment: use getGlobalVisibleRect()